# manim does not add svg text to the movie

Tags: svg, text, arabic, manim

I want to add persian text to my video.I want to use the SVG file but the text inside is not displayed.
[This is](https://svgshare.com/s/SHu) my sample file

this is my python code:

```
from manimlib.imports import *

class aa(Scene):
    def construct(self):

        a=SVGMobject(r"/home/lpp/programing/manim/khodesh/svgfile")
        a.set_color("#00FFFf")
        self.add(a)
        self.wait()
```

and this is the last frame
[image]

how can i add text to my video

Comment: Presumably you should report your problem here: https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/issues

Comment: The link you posted doesn't work. Please update it.